# Azure Synapse: Target Spark pool specified in Spark job definition is not in succeeded state. Current state: Provisioning

Tags: apache-spark, package, azure-synapse

I am trying to assign a few workspace packages to the Apache Spark pools in the Azure Synapse Analytics Workspace. Corresponding wheel files were uploaded to the workspace package manager. And I am assigning them to the specific spark pools. But when I apply these settings for the Spark pool, it says

> Target Spark pool specified in Spark job definition is not in succeeded state. Current state: Provisioning

Someone guide how to overcome this error and successfully assign packages to my spark pool.

Comment: Did you ever discover the cause/fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

This error message is displayed when the spark pool resource did take longer than expected to provision. But after provisioning is completed you shouldn't see this error. If you still see this error we recommend you to file a support ticket for deeper analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, and was getting the same error continuously. I've tried to stop and re-start the pool, but still couldn't delete or re-assign new workspace packages.

I only managed to get it working through the Apache Spark pool resource, rather than through Synapse GUI, following the following tutorial:

[Tutorial on how to fix Azure Synapse failing update package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/663889/azure-synapse-spark-pool-failing-to-update-package)

The tutorial above shows the solution for "Requirement files" but also works with "Workspace packages"

If this doesn't work, check if you have any notebooks connected to that Spark Pool. If so, reconnect them to another Spark Pool and commit the change. This should clear the provisioning state.